# operator norm of a matrix and the largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is it true that for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$, with real entries, and where all eigenvalues are real, and non zero, the operator norm ( where$||A|| = \max_{|x|=1} |Ax|$ with |.| is the standard length in $\mathbb{R}^{n}) is the same as the largest eigenvalue in absolute value? 
If it is true, can someone please give me a reference for this result?

If it is not true, what if we assume that eigenvalues are also distinct, would that make it true?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true.  Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1000 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.  The eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $2$, but the norm of $A$ is not $2$.

(The norm of $A$ is larger than $2$, because
$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1000 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1000 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.)

Comment: Sorry, I edited to assume eigenvalues are not zero.